# What's the correct JSON format for authentication with F3 PHP?

Tags: php, json, authentication, fat-free-framework

http://fatfreeframework.com/auth

http://fatfreeframework.com/jig

When using a JIG database with JSON, what's the correct JSON file format to make it work? Unfortunately, the documentation is lacking a bit and only gives incomplete snippets of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add some records with the Jig Mapper:

```
$mapper = new \DB\Jig\Mapper($db, $file);
$mapper->username = 'userA';
$mapper->password = '57d82jg05';
$mapper->save();
$mapper->reset();
$mapper->username = 'userB';
$mapper->password = 'kbjd94973';
$mapper->save();
```

Then the json file will be created, with an auto-generated record id, which looks like:

```
{
    "548723b9f06c78.10153217": {
        "username": "userA",
        "password": "57d82jg05"       
    },
    "54f9c763934745.48648465": {
        "username": "userB",
        "password": "kbjd94973"       
    }
}
```